Different ways to get expected values in the calculation of optimal doubling rates in gambling information theory
I’m reading Thomas Cover’s Elements of Information Theory and got confused about the following two equations:
(6.23) is the definition of the optimal conditional doubling rate for $X$, supposing we have side information $Y$ and

$(X, Y)$ have joint probability mass function $p(x,y)$.

Horse $X\in\{1,2,...,m\}$ win the race with probability $p(x)$ and odds of $o(x)$ for $1$.

Vector $b(x|y)$ denotes a conditional betting strategy when $y$ is observed, with $b(x|y)\geq 0$ and $\sum_x{b(x|y)=1}$.

$S is the ratio of wealth after and before a bet.


\begin{equation}
W^*(X|Y)=\max_{b(x|y)}{E[logS]}=\max_{b(x|y)}{\sum{p(x,y)\log{o(x)b(x|y)}}}
\end{equation}
$\\$
(6.31) is a special case of (6.23), where the doubling rate of $X_k$ is conditioned on all its precedents in the sequence $\{X_k\}$.
\begin{equation}
W^*(X_k|X_{k-1}, X_{k-2}, ..., X_1)=E[\max_{b(.|X_{k-1}, X_{k-2}, ..., X_1)}{E[\log{S(X_k)|X_{k-1}, X_{k-2}, ..., X_1}]}]
\end{equation}
$\\$
For both equations, $W^*(.|.)$ denotes the optimal conditional doubling rate for the variable left to the bar when the variable(s) right to the bar are observed.
I wondered why the expected value, i.e., $E[.]$, is different in (6.23) than in (6.31). Apparently, (6.23) denotes the expected value over the $p(X, Y)$ distribution. In contrast, the inner $E[.]$ of (6.31) denotes the expected value over the distribution of $p(X_k)$ when $X_1$ through $X_{k-1}$ are observed. So does the outer $E[.]$ denote the expected value over the distribution of $p(X_{k-1}, X_{k-2}, …, X_1)$? Why is there a split of the joint distribution into two in (6.31)?

Welcome to MSE. It is in your best interest that you type your posts (using MathJax) instead of posting links to pictures.
